# How do I add JSON data into a wordpress page?

Tags: html, json, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to view a json file on a worpdress themed page. I have downloaded the json data file. I uploaded the file to my Wordpress site under the root directory.  I have tried multiple ways to show the data but nothing is working. How do I show the data and then format it?

Comment: Here you go: https://codeable.io/community/how-to-import-json-into-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For decoration, it depends what the data is.  To get your data in to an array variable, if it's in a file already uploaded, I would do something like this in PHP:

```
$data_json = file_get_contents("path/to/the/json/file");
$data_arr = json_decode($data_json, true);
var_dump($data_arr);
```